# How to decrease pdf size by commenting out hyperrefs?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, size

In my pdf file I have hundreds of hyperrefs for figures, sections, cited paper authors, urls, and dois, so that when clicking onto one of those frames links, the reader is immediately brought to those locations, like a figure, section or the bibliography. Some time ago, I read that this functionality increases the size of a pdf file. I wouldn't mind to decrease its' size, but when commenting out the package `\usepackage{hyperrefs}` and compile the tex file nothing happens to the pdf file and the framed links are still all over the pdf. What am I missing here?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                     
\usepackage{lmodern}                         

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}

\usepackage[]{natbib}                        
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}              
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}        
\settocbibname{References}                   
\usepackage{hyperref}                        
\usepackage{doi}

%%Appendix stuff
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}

\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
\endgroup}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there's no other package or the class loading the package `hyperref` already? In this case, commenting `\usepackage{hyperref}` has no effect.

Comment: And are you sure the PDF actually compiled after commenting out the `hyperref` package?  Check the PDF file modification time to verify.

Comment: I added all the preamble code that I guess is somehow related to these links. Btw, the list of tables and figures is all marked as well, that's why I added the respective `lot` and `lof` code as well. Yes, I also checked the file size after commenting out; it was about 1.1MB smaller compared to the whole file of 21MB size.

Comment: Sorry, only 110KB.

Comment: If you want to reduce the size of a PDF, the first step is to re-rasterize all the images with a graphics editor.

Comment: But can the hyperlinks be a significant issue in increasing memory?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can calculate this by your own:

let's say there are `100` hyperlinks for urls (seems to be the variant with most characters).
Example url is `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301783/how-to-decrease-pdf-size-by-commenting-out-hyperrefs`
That url contains 99 characters.  One character has `8 bit = 1 Byte`, so we get `1 Byte * 99 * 100 = 9900 Byte`. You can add some more Byte for the linking to the url, but that only doubles this number (`19800 Byte = 19,3 kByte` (`1 kByte = 1024 Byte`)), not more.

One image (depending on the values of size, dpi, number of colours) can be reduced from 10 MB to 5 MByte or less (depending on the need for printing the document). You mentioned you have hundrets of images, urls, etc.  Let's say there are `100` images, then you can for example reduce your pdf file with reworking of the image like `100 Images * 5 MByte reduced = 5000 MByte` you saved ...

**Conclusion**: rework your images to be as small as possible and as big as needed ...